# Sencha touch localization

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I m developing an sencha touch app with multiple locale
i have developed the multiple locale file for each language
according to this link
http://wtcindia.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/localizing-sencha-touch-application/#comment-780

but my problem is at the time of loading i m attaching the app-en_US.js locale file and when user select the language for example (german) then new local file is added in the head tag of html app-GE_de.js

but when i run the application and select the german language still text are displaying in english

i m adding the javascript locale file like this

```
  var th = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
  s.setAttribute('src','locale/app-'+lang+'.js');
  th.appendChild(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include the app-GE_de.js instead of app-en_US.js file from the start, does it work correctly?  If so, then you are probably not destroying the old components and recreating them.

Keep in mind, just changing a global property won't update all references to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is, that you have to recreate the ui elements where you use localized text. I made a custom component called Sencha Localization that also includes the problem with recreating ui elements. Checkout https://github.com/bwidtmann/sencha_localization or http://market.sencha.com